# Oracle alter table to allow a team to support several charities if they wish change the database to satisfy this requirement

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi i need help with the following question:

Following requests from several teams, Run Monash would like to allow a team to support
several charities if they wish. Where a team does support several charities they must nominate,
one charity as their prime charity, the one they will provide the main support to.
Change the database to satisfy this requirement.
After making this change add the 'Salvation Army' as the second charity to team number 1.

The team table currently looks like this:

```
      TEAMNO TEAMNAME                       CARNDATE  TEAMNOMEMBER CHARNAME                          ENTRYID
---------- ------------------------------ --------- ------------ ------------------------------ ----------
         1 Gentle Earth                   04/APR/18            2 Amnesty International                   5
         2 Happy Feet                     04/APR/18            2 Beyond Blue                            14
         3 Avengers                       06/MAY/19            2 Salvation Army                         37
         4 Footloose                      06/MAY/19            3 Salvation Army                         38
         5 Happy Feet                     06/MAY/19            4 Amnesty International                  30
```

This is what i attempted

```
alter table team add (
    seccharname       VARCHAR2(30),
    primechar         VARCHAR2(30),
);
UPDATE team

INSERT into team (teamno,seccharname,primechar) VALUES ( values (1,'salvation army','Amnesty International');
```

Not sure what to do to satisfy the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

Your alter statement needs little bit correction. You already have CHARNAME column so you can only rename that to primechar.

```
ALTER TABLE team RENAME CHARNAME TO primechar;
```

Then Just correct your update statement -

```
UPDATE team
SET seccharname = 'salvation army',
    primechar = 'Amnesty International'
WHERE TEAMNO = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a `MERGE` statement would suit best for your case :

```
MERGE INTO team t
USING ( SELECT 1 as teamno,
               'salvation army' as seccharname,
               'Amnesty International' as primechar 
          FROM dual
      ) t2
   ON (t2.teamno=t.teamno)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET seccharname=t2.seccharname, primechar=t2.primechar
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (teamno, seccharname, primechar) 
      VALUES ( t2.teamno, t2.seccharname, t2.primechar )
```

if key column(`teamno`) matches the newly added null columns will be populated, otherwise they're inserted with null values for the rest of the columns(`teamname`,`carndate`,`teamnomember`).